# ZLib Compression adds unwanted characters to data

Tags: c++, binary, zlib

I have the following routine, which simply Uncompresseses a gz file, and then Compresseses back to gz. However, it is adding some extra characters at the beginning of the data. I'm wondering why this could be?

It seems something in the compress_string function is causing this, but I cant find out where.

Also, not sure whether the outbuffer array needs to be a larger size, or the actual size of the compressed file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "zlib-1.2.8/zlib.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

#if defined(MSDOS) || defined(OS2) || defined(WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
#  include <fcntl.h>
#  include <io.h>
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file) setmode(fileno(file), O_BINARY)
#else
#  define SET_BINARY_MODE(file)
#endif

#define CHUNK 16384

using namespace std;

bool gzipInflate( const std::string& compressedBytes, std::string& uncompressedBytes ) {
    if ( compressedBytes.size() == 0 ) {
        uncompressedBytes = compressedBytes ;
        return true ;
    }

    uncompressedBytes.clear() ;

    unsigned full_length = compressedBytes.size() ;
    unsigned half_length = compressedBytes.size() / 2;

    unsigned uncompLength = full_length ;
    char* uncomp = (char*) calloc( sizeof(char), uncompLength );

    z_stream strm;
    strm.next_in = (Bytef *) compressedBytes.c_str();
    strm.avail_in = compressedBytes.size() ;
    strm.total_out = 0;
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;

    bool done = false ;

    if (inflateInit2(&strm, (16+MAX_WBITS)) != Z_OK) {
        free( uncomp );
        return false;
    }

    while (!done) {
        // If our output buffer is too small
        if (strm.total_out >= uncompLength ) {
            // Increase size of output buffer
            char* uncomp2 = (char*) calloc( sizeof(char), uncompLength + half_length );
            memcpy( uncomp2, uncomp, uncompLength );
            uncompLength += half_length ;
            free( uncomp );
            uncomp = uncomp2 ;
        }

        strm.next_out = (Bytef *) (uncomp + strm.total_out);
        strm.avail_out = uncompLength - strm.total_out;

        // Inflate another chunk.
        int err = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        if (err == Z_STREAM_END) done = true;
        else if (err != Z_OK)  {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (inflateEnd (&strm) != Z_OK) {
        free( uncomp );
        return false;
    }

    for ( size_t i=0; i<strm.total_out; ++i ) {
        uncompressedBytes += uncomp[ i ];
    }
    free( uncomp );
    return true ;
}

/** Compress a STL string using zlib with given compression level and return
 * the binary data. */
std::string compress_string(const std::string& str, int compressionlevel = Z_BEST_COMPRESSION)
{
    z_stream zs;                        // z_stream is zlib's control structure
    memset(&zs, 0, sizeof(zs));

    if (deflateInit(&zs, compressionlevel) != Z_OK)
        throw(std::runtime_error("deflateInit failed while compressing."));

    zs.next_in = (Bytef*)str.data();
    zs.avail_in = str.size();           // set the z_stream's input

    int ret;
    char outbuffer[322768];
    std::string outstring;

    // retrieve the compressed bytes blockwise
    do {
        zs.next_out = reinterpret_cast<Bytef*>(outbuffer);
        zs.avail_out = sizeof(outbuffer);

        ret = deflate(&zs, Z_FINISH);

        if (outstring.size() < zs.total_out) {
            // append the block to the output string
            outstring.append(outbuffer,zs.total_out - outstring.size());
        }
    }
    while (ret == Z_OK);

    deflateEnd(&zs);

    if (ret != Z_STREAM_END) {          // an error occurred that was not EOF
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Exception during zlib compression: (" << ret << ") " << zs.msg;
        throw(std::runtime_error(oss.str()));
    }

    return outstring;
}

/* Reads a file into memory. */
bool loadBinaryFile( const std::string& filename, std::string& contents ) {
    // Open the gzip file in binary mode
    FILE* f = fopen( filename.c_str(), "rb" );
    if ( f == NULL )
        return false ;

    // Clear existing bytes in output vector
    contents.clear();

    // Read all the bytes in the file
    int c = fgetc( f );
    while ( c != EOF ) {
        contents +=  (char) c ;
        c = fgetc( f );
    }
    fclose (f);

    return true ;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Read the gzip file data into memory
    std::string fileData ;
    if ( !loadBinaryFile( "myfilein.gz", fileData ) ) {
        printf( "Error loading input file." );
        return 0 ;
    }

    // Uncompress the file data
    std::string data ;
    if ( !gzipInflate( fileData, data ) ) {
        printf( "Error decompressing file." );  
        return 0 ;  
    }  

    // Print the data  
    //printf( "Data: \"" );
    for ( size_t i=0; i<data.size(); ++i ) {  
        printf( "%c", data[i] );
    }  
    //printf ( "\"\n" );


    std::string outy;
    // Compress the file data
    outy = compress_string(data, 0);

    //Write the gzipped data to a file.
    FILE *handleWrite=fopen("myfileout.gz","wb");
    fwrite(outy.data(),outy.size(),1,handleWrite);

    fclose(handleWrite);

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to try to debug your code (which is not a free service offered here), but I can immediately observe that your code does not do what your question claims. Your `inflateInit2()` does set you up to decompress a gzip stream. However your `deflateInit()` sets up compression to the zlib format, *not* the gzip format.

I recommend that you read the documentation in [zlib.h](http://zlib.net/manual.html). After reading all of that, you may want to look at this [well-commented example of the use of zlib](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html).